# Google analytics https iframe does not work on chrome and safari

Tags: xhtml, iframe, https

So I'm trying to embed the google analytics login page onto a page. Works fine on IE and Firefox. The website is hosted on a local machine.

Code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/analytics/settings/?et=reset&hl=en" height="1000px" width="100%">Your browser does not support iframes.</iframe>
```

Is this a bug in chrome safari or can I adapt my xhtml to fix this?

**Edit** :In the end I used the Google Analytics API with this PHP library http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/
and google chart api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is setting response headers to explicitly block the loading of these pages into an iframe. The headers are respected by newer browsers, but not implemented in older ones. I suspect you're using a version of IE below 8 if this is working for you.

Comment: Ah I thought they may be blocking it somehow.

I've since found a php library which pulls data from google analytics.
I'm loving the power of the google query browser. After I run the data through google's chart api it should achieve a similar result.

it seems strange that there is no existing open source software which embeds GA charts into a website.